# Heads up before trying Mapbox vector tiles services flexibility with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, performance, mapbox, vector-tiles

if I load Mapbox vector tiles services in my map using OpenLayers 3, can I perform the functions like on click popup or on hover popup, highlight etc?

Is it advisable and mature enough? As I [saw this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/tile-vector.html) it has a warning of browser becoming unresponsive. Has anyone tried to load say ten vector tiles in one map?